# Maximum number of events on a same time slot - Google Calendar

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

In Google calendar on the same time slot, say 9 to 9:30, how many events can be scheduled. Is there any limit? I couldn't find this info anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

### You can find the general limits for Google Calendar [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en) and for Calendar API in specific [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/pricing) and [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors).

So while the limits considering how many events you can create and there is also a rate limit - there is no restriction about how many of those events take place within the same time slot.